# How to read newline character('\n') delimited strings until EOF in C?

Tags: c, string

For example, I am writing a C function that replace a substring `s1` in string `source` with a new string `s2`. But I am having trouble with reading the input from stdin. I also want it to end until an `EOF` is met.

I search a lot about "read until EOF" and "read a string containing whitespace", but I didnt make it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
{
  char source[120], s1[20], s2[20];
  ...
  //what ever to input multiple cases of source, s1, and s2 until EOF is met
  replace(source, s1, s2);
  printf("%s\n",source); 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably wanted to ask _how to read a file_?

Comment: Actually I am working on a problem on an online judge system, and all the data are input from stdin ending with EOF. so... that's why I am asking..

Comment: Just to clarify this: There is **no** such characters as EOF. Due to this it cannot terminate anything nor could it be read.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to do something like this:

```
char buffer[1234];

while (NULL != fgets(buffer, 1234, stdin))
{
  /* Do something with the 0-terniated content of buffer. */
}

if (ferror(stdin))
{
   /* An error occurred reading from stdin. */
}
```

For reference:

- [`man fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html)
- [`man ferror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ferror.3.html)

---

If you cannot define an upper limit for the number of characters until a new-line, the [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) function might be of interest, as it is capable to allocate as much memory as necessary to hold all characters until the next new-line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `feof` function.

```
while(!feof(stdin)) {
     //read data with scanf, gets, fgets, etc...
}
```

To send an EOF press `CTRL+D`.
View the manual for more information about `feof` function. (`man feof` on terminal)

Comment: thx, but any other alternatives? It's sad that the OJ restricts the use of feof function.

Comment: the 'fgets' function does it automatically. It stops to read when it read a '\n' or a 'EOF'. 
char* buffer = malloc(DIM);
char* read = fgets(buffer, DIM, stdin);

Comment: The answer to "*“while( !feof( file ) )” is always wrong*" http://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/694576

Comment: Thanks for your advice @alk...but is the second alternative, that I've proposed, correct according to you?

Comment: Yes/no, `fgets()` **could** to the job. See my answer on details.

Answer (score 0):

Check this and give me your opinion :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Replace_Function(String[] s1,String[]  s2){
String source[120], s1[20], s2[20];

//This is what u want???? 
while (getchar() != EOF)
 {
   S1=S2;
 }

  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece of code may help you:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
   // do smt
}
```

We must declare c to be a big enough to hold any value that getchar return. So we don't use char since
c must be big enough to hold EOF (which is integer defined in `<stdio.h>`)

Comment: how can int store a string?